# Rails refactoring each cicle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In RoR is possible to do it

```
i=[]
Structure.with_roles(:admin).each do |s|
 i<<s.outfits.pluck(:id)
end
puts i
```

in a single line code?
In need to have this function in a single line becouse i'm writing cancan ability file:

```
i=[]
can :destroy, Outfit, id: Structure.with_roles(:admin).each do |s|
 i<<s.outfits.pluck(:id)
end
```

Comment: you'd rather use `map`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
puts Structure.with_roles(:admin).map{|s| s.outfits.pluck(:id)}
```

though you would get an array of arrays, so you may (or may not) want to use `.flatten`.